# Combine JSLink of UserContextFilterWebPart and a XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: filter, user, jslink, joined-view

I have a `WebPartPage` which includes a `XsltListViewWebPart` and a `UserContextFilterWebPart`. In order to filter the results by the user office and 'connect' the two webparts, I added the parameter `<ParameterBinding Name="Office" Location="None" DefaultValue="" />`.
As described in [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169940/using-author-in-caml-join/169961#169961) I encountered problems using the `<JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>` tag in order to have a nice rendering with more functionalities of my list.

My View including the Join:

```
<View //all the view attributes >
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Buro"/>
                <Value Type="Text">{Office}</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="FALSE"/>
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Created"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Author"/>
        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Status"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Priority"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Buero"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Position"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Body"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Joins>
        <Join Type="LEFT" ListAlias="Users">
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Author" RefType="ID"/>
                <FieldRef List="Users" Name="ID"/>
            </Eq>
        </Join>
    </Joins>
    <ProjectedFields>
        <Field Name="Buro" Type="Lookup" List="Users" ShowField="Office"/>
    </ProjectedFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">999</RowLimit>
    <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
</View>
```

Removing the JSLink tag (leaving it empty) i get the old view:
[image]
Furthermore in this case the columns are not filterable anymore...only sortable.

Removing the join i get the new one:
[image]

Somebody else had this problem? 
Solutions?